# conversion from unsigned to integer in vhdl

Tags: type-conversion, vhdl

I'm trying to convert one signal to another type using numeric_std:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity ftable is
GENERIC(      c : integer := 3;
              m : integer := 4;
              n : integer := 8;
              d : integer := 16; 
              stored_data : unsigned := x"000000010002010001010102");           
    Port ( 
              a : in unsigned (7 downto 0);
              b : in unsigned (7 downto 0);
           f_one : out  unsigned (15 downto 0);                 
           f_two : out  unsigned (15 downto 0));
end ftable;

architecture behavioral of ftable is

    signal row_id : unsigned (7 downto 0); 
    signal col_id : unsigned (7 downto 0); 
    signal r_temp : integer;
    signal c_temp : integer;

begin

    process (a, b) 
        variable addr: integer;     
    begin

        row_id <= "00000000";
        col_id <= "00000000";
        r_temp <= 0;
        c_temp <= 2;

        row_id(m  downto 0) <= b((n - 1) downto (n - (m + 1)));
        col_id(m  downto 0) <= a((n - 1) downto (n - (m + 1)));

        r_temp <= to_integer(row_id);
        c_temp <= to_integer(col_id);

        addr := d * (c * to_integer(row_id) + to_integer(col_id)) + r_temp + c_temp;
        f_one <= stored_data(addr to addr + d - 1);
        f_two <= stored_data(addr + d to addr + d + d - 1);
    end process;

end behavioral;
```

Code synthesizes well and when I simulate with iSim I get col_id = 00000001 and c_temp = 0 (checked in instances and processes tab).

My question is why do I get 0 instead of 1?

Edit: when simulating I also get warning: NUMERIC_STD.TO_INTEGER: metavalue detected, returning 0

Comment: You have row_id and col_id in expressions on the right hand side of signal assignment statements and those signals are not in the process sensitivity list. The process doesn't resume simulation after row_id or col_id are updated and the implicit wait statement as the last process statement is encountered. You can generally expect synthesis results to work correctly (when no logic loops are present), sensitivity lists are mostly ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `std_logic` values that can be converted to 0 or 1 are `'0'`, `'1'`, `'L'`, and `'h'`, and other values as `'U'`, `'X'`, `'Z'`, `'W'`, `'-'` which are called metavalues.

If any of these metavalues are in the `std_logic_vector` that is converted with `to_integer`, then 0 is returned together with the warning you see.

Problem is also that the process is only sensitive to `a` and `b`, but should include all signals that are read e.g. also `col_id` in order to re-execute the process when any of the intermediate signals are changed.  So add all signal read in the process to the sensitivity list, or for VHDL-2008 use `process (all)`.

Comment: I think that maybe for a while col_id is undefined, but finally it is 0x01 but the c_temp is still 0

Comment: OK, after updating with entire entity, I have updated my answer with more info.

Comment: It was sensitivity list issue. Thank you very much!